# Why is my closure variable cleared after using $.each on JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, closures

Consider the following example:

```
var features = [];

$.getJSON(annotations_url, function(data) { 
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    features.push(wkt_parser.read(val.annotation.wkt_data));
    // at this point, "features" contains objects
  });
});

annotationLayer.addFeatures(features);
// here, it is empty again
```

Here, I expect `features` to continuously grow. However, in the last line, `features` is empty again.

Why is that and how would I correctly push values  to `features` from within the `$.each` (or rather the anonymous function inside)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$.getJSON` call is asynchronous, so `annotationLayer.addFeatures` is probably being executed before the JSON request has finished. Call the `addFeatures` method *inside* the `$.getJSON` call, after the `.each` loop.

If you need to perform more stuff with `features`, consider creating a new function (which includes the `addFeatures` method you need to call), and then call this new function after the `.each` loop inside the `$.getJSON` call.

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the asynchronous behaviour of the `$.getJSON` function. Move `annotationLayer.addFeatures(features);` inside the `$.getJSON` function.

The `features` variable isn't being "cleared"; rather, it has not being populated when `annotationLayer.addFeatures(features);` is executed.